# Can batteries be connected in parallel then in series then in parallel again?

Tags: batteries, parallel, series

I'm planning a modular and swappable battery system where each module is for example 12S2P (2 parallel Li-Ion battery connected in 12S.)

Can I connect two 12S2P modules in parallel making it a 12S4P providing each module has the same voltage and BMS?

Edit:
@Finbarr thanks, I've already read the first, the second one partially answer, it seems to be a similar situation. The answer concerns were about the sudden load on one of the packs when one dies (not a concern in my case) and about recharging and BMS chaining that can be "solved" by charging each module individually and setting the same Voltage in the BMS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It it safe to connect Li-Ion batteries in series and then in parallel?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296446/it-it-safe-to-connect-li-ion-batteries-in-series-and-then-in-parallel)

Comment: Or [this one?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465630/connecting-battery-packs-in-parallel-and-series-each-with-their-own-bms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My primary concern to address your question:

> **Can I connect two 12S2P modules in parallel** making it a 12S4P providing each module has the same voltage and BMS?

My concern would be about battery packs being at the same State of Charge (SoC), battery-pack size and age.

If you assure your setup has *“the same voltage and BMS”*, you *most probably* will be ok.
*Probably*, because the battery packs should also have the same Ah capacity and similar age, so the *internal resistance along the discharge curve* is similar. And that both battery-packs are protected from overcharge and overdischarge.
If these concerns are addressed, you will be good.

Answer (score -2):

You can do anything you want with specs for Delta V, ESR and I max. How you achieve this depends on those specs probably with switching L regulators to equalize V and stay under I max.

dI=dV dt / L with low DCR and FET and diode rated for 10*Imax for efficiency using hysteric feedback. This essentially an active BMS for transition from 24P2S to 12S4P with dV=12S difference.